# What is a "linear chain" in Graph Theory?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, topological-graph-theory

What is a **linear chain** in the context of graphs and trees?

For example:

> a topological sort forms a ***linear chain***

What does a *linear chain* mean in the example above?

Another example from [Introduction to Algorithms (CH 12)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms):

> Basic operations on a binary search tree take time proportional to the height of the tree. For a complete binary tree with $n$ nodes, such operations run in $\Theta(\lg{}n)$ worst-case time. If the tree is a ***linear chain*** of $n$ nodes, however, the same operations take $\Theta(n)$ worst-case time.

Comment: Can you state where this is from, and give some more context?

Comment: Sure, I added another example

Comment: [Looks like](https://books.google.com/books?id=i-bUBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA286&dq=Basic%20operations%20on%20a%20binary%20search%20tree%20take%20time%20proportional%20to%20the%20height%20of%20the%20tree.&pg=PA286#v=onepage&q=Basic%20operations%20on%20a%20binary%20search%20tree%20take%20time%20proportional%20to%20the%20height%20of%20the%20tree.&f=false) you mean the linear chain takes $\Theta(n)$ time.

Comment: Typo! Corrected.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From context, it's clear that this means a graph which is simply a path, like

```
1--2--3--4--...--n
```

so that every vertex has degree 2 except the first and last.